# Parent element Should Hide if there is no Child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list item. Each list contain class .filter-tag. 
when I click on each .filter-tag it goes hidden.
Here is the Example: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dg8nndbh/1/)**

But I am wanting when all the list item is hidden, **parent(.filter-tag-has-content)** of this list item should also hide. Means if no list element is visible parent will hide also but if one if visible parent should stay visible too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="filter-tag-container">
    <ul class="filter-tag-has-content">
        <li class="filter-tag" id="fl-1">
            <span class="tag-name">Filter Option 1</span>
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
         </li>
        <li class="filter-tag" id="fl-2">
            <span class="tag-name">Filter Option 2</span>
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-tag" id="fl-3">
            <span class="tag-name">Filter Option 3</span>
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-tag" id="fl-4">
            <span class="tag-name">Filter Option 4</span>
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-tag" id="fl-5">
            <span class="tag-name">Filter Option 5</span>
            <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.filter-tag').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the length of the visible list items as you click them. Once there are none left, hide the list.

```
$('.filter-tag').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if(!$('.filter-tag:visible').length) $('ul.filter-tag-has-content').hide()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dg8nndbh/2/)**

Or to use on multiple containers:

```
$('.filter-tag').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if(!$(this).siblings(':visible').length)$(this).parent().hide()
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vfdgnqky/)**

Comment: Maybe only select siblings, or select from the current parent? OP might want multiple containers.

Comment: @parchment - True, answer updated to be more generic.

Comment: Just for curiosity is this possible to select the parent div from the outside of :
$('.filter-tag').click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});

This code ?

Comment: `closest('div.filter-tag-container')` should do it.

Comment: you can do it. `$(this).parents('div.filter-tag-container')`

Comment: Thank you but my curiosity was can this be made like :

if ( $(".filter-tag-has-content").children(".filter-tag").css('display') != 'block') { 
   $(this).fadeOut();

}
?

Comment: With a single list you could do something along those lines.

Comment: You could, but you'd need to use `$(this)` to reference the proper list and list items.

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
$('.filter-tag').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    if( ! $(this).parent().children(':visible').length > 0){
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});
```